# Website does not advertise HTTP in its NPN Extension spdy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl, spdy

I have configure Apache with SPDY (and PHP-FPM). Everything works fine. However, spdycheck.org shows me following error:

> HTTP Over SSL Not Supported!
>
> This website only supports SPDY over SSL, and does not advertise HTTP in its NPN Extension. Web  browsers without SPDY support may not be able to access this site

It's important to note that I do NOT wish to support HTTP. However, I do need to support SSL without SPDY.
I'm not sure what to change in the conf file to do that. Any pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: It is easier to tell what to change if we can see the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm! The issue was with the version I had compiled: https://github.com/eousphoros/mod-spdy/issues/19

Comment: I'm getting the same thing using the .deb package straight from Google.  Any other ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a version mismatch? Google's binary isn't for Apache 2.4

Comment: My problem was that I didn't have TLS enabled on that server (like a dope).  See http://serverfault.com/questions/637262/missing-npn-extension.