# Missing NPN Extension

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl, spdy

I'm trying to set up mod_spdy with Apache (mod_spdy-0.9.4.3-r420 and apache2-2.2.22-13+deb7u3 on Debian Wheezy).  As far as I can tell, everything is the way it's supposed to be, but I'm getting the "Missing NPN Extension in SSL/TLS Handshake" error from http://spdycheck.org/.

`mods-enabled/ssl.load` just has:  (everything else is commented out)

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl_with_npn.so
```

and I can confirm with lsof that that is the file that apache is using right now.

Any clue why SSL isn't doing the NPN thing so that mod_spdy will work?

I have another box that seems to be configured exactly the same in this regard and it is working just fine.  I'm assuming I'm missing some detail that is different :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.  Apache, for some reason, was set to use SSL3 only.  Adding TLS v1 (and v1.1, v1.2) made everything work. TLS is required for SPDY to work.  I changed my apache config to have

```
SSLProtocol +SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```

And that works like a charm.

Even better, leave out SSLv3 altogether, as it's known to be insecure:

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```